# BufferCB not being called by SampleGrabber

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I'm using a SampleGrabber to get audio data, however my BufferCB method is not being executed. What am I doing wrong ?

```
//add Sample Grabber
            IBaseFilter pSampleGrabber = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_SampleGrabber));
            hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pSampleGrabber, "SampleGrabber");
            checkHR(hr, "Can't add Sample Grabber");

        AMMediaType pSampleGrabber_pmt = new AMMediaType();
        //pSampleGrabber_pmt.majorType = MediaType.Audio;
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.subType = MediaSubType.PCM;
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatType = FormatType.WaveEx;
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.fixedSizeSamples = true;
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatSize = 18;
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.sampleSize = 2;

        WaveFormatEx pSampleGrabber_Format = new WaveFormatEx();
        pSampleGrabber_Format.wFormatTag = 1;
        pSampleGrabber_Format.nChannels = 1;
        pSampleGrabber_Format.nSamplesPerSec = 48000;
        pSampleGrabber_Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = 96000;
        pSampleGrabber_Format.nBlockAlign = 2;
        pSampleGrabber_Format.wBitsPerSample = 16;
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(pSampleGrabber_Format));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(pSampleGrabber_Format, pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatPtr, false);
        hr = ((ISampleGrabber)pSampleGrabber).SetMediaType(pSampleGrabber_pmt);
        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(pSampleGrabber_pmt);
        checkHR(hr, "Can't set media type to sample grabber");

        ISampleGrabber pGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber; 
        pGrabber = (ISampleGrabber)pSampleGrabber;
        pGrabber.SetCallback(null, 1);
```

My BufferCB method is like

```
public int BufferCB(double SampleTime, IntPtr pBuffer, int BufferLen)
        {

            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created and configured one instance `pSampleGrabber` and then you are attaching your callback to another unused idling instance `pGrabber`.

You need

```
pSampleGrabber as ISampleGrabber
```

instead of

```
new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber
```

Comment: I get the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

Comment: Oh wait, you are doing even more weird things. `pGrabber = new ...` is completely useless as you are are immeately releasing this instance. `SetCallback(null` - what do you expect here? You are passing `null` where your callback is expected...

Comment: Oh,I see.. So I need to implement ISampleGrabberCB and then put my implementation of BufferCB there ?

Comment: Yes this is how SG finds your `BufferCB`. Actually, I personally always prefer `SampleCB` to `BufferCB`.